# How to fix the qtip position when using cytoscape-qtip.js

Tags: qtip, cytoscape.js

I'd like to show detailed information when clicking on a certain node. Instead of showing information in related to the position of node, I'd like to place the information at a fixed position (for example, top right corner of `<div id="cy"></div>`).

Normally, we can use the `position.target` attribute to set the position. But when I set `target` as fixed coordinate values, it doesn't seem to work because the qtip info still appears on the default position (which is `my: 'left',at: 'bottom center'`).

Did misunderstand the usage of target? Below is part of my sample code.

```
    cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function (e) { 
        var node = e.cyTarget;

        if (!node.isParent()) {
            node.qtip({
                content: function () {
                    return 'show some information'
                },
                position: {
                    target: [100,100] // for example
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
                    tip: {
                        width: 16,
                        height: 8
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Options:

(1) Don't use the qtip plugin.  Use qtip itself on your div, and show it manually on node taps.

(2) Use a strategy similar to (1) but without qtips altogether.  If you're not pointing at the node of interest, you may as well just use a div with the info.

Comment: Thanks for your nice suggestions, @maxkfranz.